# Randomise Bootstrap Carousel Slides except 1st slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel with 5 slides and would like to randomise them but always keep the same slide at the front.

So it could load and be any of these orders for example.

1 3 2 5 4 // 1 2 5 4 3 // 1 5 2 4 3

I could use javascript with math floor but this would apply to them all rather than only slides 2,3,4,5

Is there a method of doing this? It obviously does not need to be native to bootstrap. Each slide is a `<div>` element rather than `<li>` and I am using the data attributes rather than javascript to initialize the slider, I can change this if required.

Carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000" data-pause="hover">

 <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner left-bottom-corner right-bottom-corner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="hidden-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_home'); ?>" alt="...">
      <img class="visible-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_home_mobile'); ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_icon'); ?>" alt="...">
        <?php the_field('slide_home_text'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item randomslide">
            <img class="hidden-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_1'); ?>" alt="...">
            <img class="visible-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_1_mobile'); ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_icon'); ?>" alt="...">
         <?php the_field('slide_1_text'); ?>
         </div></div>

  <div class="item randomslide">
      <img class="hidden-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_2'); ?>" alt="...">
      <img class="visible-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_2_mobile'); ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_icon'); ?>" alt="...">
         <?php the_field('slide_2_text'); ?>
         </div>
         </div>

        <div class="item randomslide">
         <img class="hidden-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_3'); ?>" alt="...">
         <img class="visible-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_3_mobile'); ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_icon'); ?>" alt="...">
         <?php the_field('slide_3_text'); ?>

         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item randomslide">
      <img class="hidden-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_4'); ?>" alt="...">
      <img class="visible-xs" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_4_mobile'); ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" src="<?php the_field('home_slide_icon'); ?>" alt="...">
         <?php the_field('slide_4_text'); ?>
         </div> 
    </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

***SOLUTION***

I managed this with a prompt from @CBroe

Below selects all of the sliders apart from the first which has the active class pre-defined then shuffles them.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var parent = $(".carousel-inner");
    var divs = $(".item").not(".item.active");
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: _“I could use javascript with math floor but this would apply to them all”_ – only if _you_ apply it “to them all.”

Comment: To mark a question as solved please accept an answer below even if it is your own answer

Comment: @ChrisBier I have to wait until tomorrow before I can do that. I will do so when I am able to. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this with a prompt from @CBroe

Below selects all of the sliders apart from the first which has the active class pre-defined then shuffles them.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var parent = $(".carousel-inner");
    var divs = $(".item").not(".item.active");
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a jQuery object with the relevant elements.

```
var $carouselLi = $('.carousel > ol > li').slice(1);
```

And an array with the allowed numbers.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
```

Then iterate through `$carouselLi` and set one of the numbers from the `array` as the elements `data-slide-to` attribute (which should determine the position within the slide).

```
$.each($carouselLi, function ( key, value ) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    this.dataset.slideTo = numbers[index];
    numbers.splice(index,1);
});
```

I'm not sure how the `bootstrap plugin` works. I assume you shouldn't initialize it until the `data-slide-to` attribute is assigned.